# I can't access files in different servers than database server name

Tags: oracle, server

I am trying to make a directory accessing a file, but error message Access is denied is raised.

To be more specific, I want to access a server from plsql different than the db server.

The server's path is : \192.168.3.15\k$\INPUT_FILES\

I tried to create a directory as below :
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY 'TEST' AS '\192.168.3.15\k$\INPUT_FILES';

an access the file via AS_READ_XLSX package

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE( AS_READ_XLSX.READ( AS_READ_XLSX.FILE2BLOB( 'TEST', 'aaa.xlsx' );
```

But I get error

> ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
>
> Access is denied.
>
> ORA-06512:  "AS_READ_XLSX", line 361

```
function file2blob
    ( p_dir varchar2
    , p_file_name varchar2
    )
  return blob
  is
    file_lob bfile;
    file_blob blob;
  begin  
    file_lob := bfilename( p_dir, p_file_name );
    dbms_lob.open( file_lob, dbms_lob.file_readonly );
    dbms_lob.createtemporary( file_blob, true );
    dbms_lob.loadfromfile( file_blob, file_lob, dbms_lob.lobmaxsize );
    dbms_lob.close( file_lob );
    return file_blob;
  exception
    when others then
      if dbms_lob.isopen( file_lob ) = 1
      then
        dbms_lob.close( file_lob );
      end if;
      if dbms_lob.istemporary( file_blob ) = 1
      then
        dbms_lob.freetemporary( file_blob );
      end if;
      raise;   --361 LINE
  end;
```

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment yet, so I am writing an answer.
Have you checked if the oracle/dba user in the - I suppose - Linux server has the right to open the file? Try giving access to the file to all users in the server.
It has happened quite a few times to me. :)